# CodeChef Array Transform Program

Tags: java

Here's the Problem Statement :

> > Given n numbers, you can perform the following operation any number of
> >     times : Choose any subset of the
> >     numbers, none of which are 0.
> >     Decrement the numbers in the subset by
> >     1, and increment the numbers not in
> >     the subset by K. Is it possible to
> >     perform operations such that all
> >     numbers except one of them become 0 ?
> >     Input : The first line contains the
> >     number of test cases T. 2*T lines
> >     follow, 2 for each case. The first
> >     line of a test case contains the
> >     numbers n and K. The next line
> >     contains n numbers, a_1...a_n. Output
> >     : Output T lines, one corresponding to
> >     each test case. For a test case,
> >     output "YES" if there is a sequence of
> >     operations as described, and "NO"
> >     otherwise.

```
Sample Input :
3
2 1
10 10
3 2
1 2 2
3 2
1 2 3

Sample Output :
YES
YES
NO

Constraints :
1 <= T <= 1000
2 <= n <= 100
1 <= K <= 10
0 <= a_i <= 1000
```

& here's my code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTransform {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no_of_tests = sc.nextInt();

        int size;
        int a[] = new int[100];
        boolean yes;
        int j;
        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_tests; i++) {
            size = sc.nextInt();
            k = sc.nextInt();
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                a[j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            yes = is_possible(a, size, k + 1);
            if (yes)
                System.out.println("YES\n");
            else
                System.out.println("NO\n");
        }
    }

    static boolean is_possible(int a[], int size, int k_1) {
        int count = 0;
        int m[] = { -1, -1 };
        int mod;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mod = a[i] % k_1;
            if (m[0] != mod && m[1] != mod) {
                if (m[0] == -1)
                    m[0] = mod;
                else if (m[1] == -1)
                    m[1] = mod;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry...What's wrong in my code? Why am I getting Wrong Answer?

Comment: What have your tried? How have you approached debugging this? What makes you think that any given answer is right or wrong? - once you know that, tracing through your logic error should be pretty routine.

Comment: @Chester, edit your question to actually include a question statement.   Also specify what results you are expecting and what you are seeing.

Comment: this is my algorithm i am using for array trm :
Assume a total of m operations are performed , for an element a_i
1)is either incremented by k x_i times or
2)decremented by 1 by y_i times
such that x_i + y_i = m (total no. of operations) ... (1)
solving for 
a_i + k*x_i - y_i = 0
=>a_i + (k+1)x_i - m = 0 , using result 1
=> m = (k+1)x_i + a_i (2)
Now m%(k+1) = a_i % (k+1)
since i have to reduce n-1 numbers to zero , these n-1 numbers must give the same remainder when divided by k+1 and the number not reduced to zero can give same or some other remainder,

Comment: so the answer is "YES" if number of distinct remainder is <=2 and "NO" otherwise,but i get WRONG ANSWER  : heres the code , need a TEST CASE WHERE THE BELOW FAILS

Comment: `these n-1 numbers must give the same remainder when divided by k+1`, I think that's true. That makes it a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one. For what cases does your code give the wrong results?

Comment: I'm getting the correct output for the sample Inputs..
but, when I submit the code, I get an error saying WRONG ANSWER!


I got a reply from some other community saying :

these n-1 numbers must give the same remainder when divided by k+1 and the number not reduced to zero can give same or some other remainder
&
so the answer is "YES" if number of distinct remainder is <=2 and "NO" otherwise

These two statements are not equivalent.


I didn't understand this.
can you explain it to me & where exactly in the code should I make the changes?

Comment: umm...
I dunno the test cases, I actually submitted this code on CodeChef & got an error saying wrong answer!
We don't get to know the test case which fails...

Comment: (I think) your logic is flawed. It's like, I want to find all primes greater than 10. All primes greater than 10 must be odd. Then you conclude, so if a number is odd and greater than 10, it is prime. In your code: the `return true` statement is wrong (you know it is odd, but that doesn't mean it is prime!). Anyway, **you** can also find the cases where it goes wrong. Write a test case. Find more sample input & output, see where it goes wrong. Try and code

Comment: @Ishtar : I'm still not able to find the flaw..
can you please help me out by telling which line statement of the code should be changed?

Comment: How about `0 0 1 1` with `k=2`? I can't solve it, but your program says "YES". `n-1 numbers must give the same remainder` and `distinct remainder is <=2` are not the same thing?

Comment: So, where in the code should I make the changes?
n-1 numbers must give the same remainder, is the right thing?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (m[0] != mod && m[1] != mod)
```

Here instead of `&&` there should be `||`. Only one of the `m`'s need to match the mod.